# Looping through array of arrays to create a model

Tags: python, node.js, arrays

This is my array of arrays

```
var arrOfArr = [['the', 'man'],
['at'],
['in']]
```

in this simple case there are only

```
the at in and  man at in
```

in this array

```
var arrofArr = [['the', 'man'],
['at'],['of']
['in']]
```

here it will be

```
the at in, the of in
and
man at in, man of in
```

and in this case

```
var myArrOfArr = [['the', 'man'],
['is',  'was', 'at'],
['and', 'of'],
['but', 'not']]
```

I want to loop through this array in a particular fashion like

all the possible combinations in downward order

like

```
the is and but, the is and not, the was and but, the was and not, the at and but, the at and not,
the is of but, the is of not, the was of but, the was of not, the at of but, the at of not,

man is and but..
man is of but.
```

The array of arrays length may vary. Can someone help me to solve this complex iteration?

I am currently doing it in nodejs, is this language fine or does python have easy tools for this?

Hi, can nodejs do the same task? is it good? please give me an opinion.

.

Comment: Maybe this can be helpful: https://docs.python.org/3.8/library/itertools.html#itertools.permutations

Answer (score 3, accepted):

itertools.product() is what you want:

```
import itertools

myArrOfArr = [['the', 'man'],
['is',  'was', 'at'],
['and', 'of'],
['but', 'not']]

for q in itertools.product(*myArrOfArr):
    print(q)
```

If you have any questions, leave a comment. :-)

Comment: Let me check it out. I will update in comments. Thank you for the quick reply 

Answer (score 2):

You can use this

```
import itertools
myArrOfArr = [['the', 'man'],
['is',  'was', 'at'],
['and', 'of'],
['but', 'not']]

arr = [' '.join(str(y) for y in x) for x in itertools.product(*myArrOfArr)]

print(arr)
#['the is and but', 'the is and not', 'the is of but', 'the is of not', 'the was and but', 'the was and not', 'the was of but', 'the was of not', 'the at and but', 'the at and not', 'the at of but', 'the at of not', 'man is and but', 'man is and not', 'man is of but', 'man is of not', 'man was and but', 'man was and not', 'man was of but', 'man was of not', 'man at and but', 'man at and not', 'man at of but', 'man at of not']
```

Answer (score 1):

```
import itertools 
myArrOfArr = [['the', 'man'],['is',  'was', 'at'],['and', 'of'],['but', 'not']]

op = list(itertools.product(*myArrOfArr)) 
print(op)
```

Answer

```
[('the', 'is', 'and', 'but'), ('the', 'is', 'and', 'not'), ('the', 'is', 'of', 'but'), ('the', 'is', 'of', 'not'), ('the', 'was', 'and', 'but'), ('the', 'was', 'and', 'not'), ('the', 'was', 'of', 'but'), ('the', 'was', 'of', 'not'), ('the', 'at', 'and', 'but'), ('the', 'at', 'and', 'not'), ('the', 'at', 'of', 'but'), ('the', 'at', 'of', 'not'), ('man', 'is', 'and', 'but'), ('man', 'is', 'and', 'not'), ('man', 'is', 'of', 'but'), ('man', 'is', 'of', 'not'), ('man', 'was', 'and', 'but'), ('man', 'was', 'and', 'not'), ('man', 'was', 'of', 'but'), ('man', 'was', 'of', 'not'), ('man', 'at', 'and', 'but'), ('man', 'at', 'and', 'not'), ('man', 'at', 'of', 'but'), ('man', 'at', 'of', 'not')]
```

here is the reference
https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/python-all-possible-permutations-of-n-lists/

Answer (score 1):

```
from itertools import product
result_array = [' '.join(map(str,x)) for x in product(*myArrOfArr)]
print(result_array)


Output 
['the is and but', 'the is and not', 'the is of but', 'the is of not', 'the 
was and but', 'the was and not', 'the was of but', 'the was of not', 'the at 
and but', 'the at and not', 'the at of but', 'the at of not', 'man is and 
but', 'man is and not', 'man is of but', 'man is of not', 'man was and but', 
'man was and not', 'man was of but', 'man was of not', 'man at and but', 'man 
at and not', 'man at of but', 'man at of not']
```